# ListItems ArrayList ListView

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Guys I'm trying to make the below code store multiple items in exampleArray but it's only grabbing the first SectionOutageListItem. Do I need to create another listItem Array to loop through it again?

```
SectionOutageListItem[] exampleArray = new SectionOutageListItem[outnums.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < outnums.size(); i++) {
        exampleArray[i] = 
      new SectionOutageListItem("Impact", impacted.get(i), "Outage No. " + outnums.get(i)),
      new SectionOutageListItem("status", status.get(i), "Outage No. " + outnums.get(i));


    }
        CustomOutageDetailListAdapter adapter = new CustomOutageDetailListAdapter(this, exampleArray);
        sectionAdapter = new SectionOutageListAdapter(getLayoutInflater(),
                adapter);
```

UPDATE:

I have a custom adapter which adds sections to a listview, the SectionOutageListItem determines how many rows are in that section. The outnums.get(i) creates multiple sections which should add the impact and status as rows for each section. It is only adding the first new SectionOutageListItem as a row and not the second one.

Custom List Adapter code

```
public class CustomOutageDetailListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SectionOutageListItem> {

private Activity context;
private SectionOutageListItem[] items;

//private final ArrayList<String> itemname;

public CustomOutageDetailListAdapter(Activity context, SectionOutageListItem[] items) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylistoutagedetails, items);
    this.items= items;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistoutagedetails, null,true);
    final SectionOutageListItem currentItem = items[position];
    if (currentItem != null) {
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    TextView txtName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        if (txtTitle != null) {
            txtTitle.setText(currentItem.item.toString());

        }
        if (txtName != null) {

             txtName.setText(currentItem.name.toString());

        }
    }
    return rowView;

};
```

Comment: A Java Array may only hold a single Object at each index.

Comment: @Trobbins so what would be my other options?

Comment: Please add a bit more information about what you are trying to do. A bit more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Trobbins points out ,
You may need to change the code as follows,

```
SectionOutageListItem[][] exampleArray = new SectionOutageListItem[outnums.size()][2];

for(int i = 0; i < outnums.size(); i++) {
    exampleArray[i][0] = 
  new SectionOutageListItem("Impact", impacted.get(i), "Outage No. " + outnums.get(i));
  exampleArray[i][1] = new SectionOutageListItem("status", status.get(i), "Outage No. " + outnums.get(i));


}
    CustomOutageDetailListAdapter adapter = new CustomOutageDetailListAdapter(this, exampleArray);
    sectionAdapter = new SectionOutageListAdapter(getLayoutInflater(),
            adapter);
```

You can also go with a `Map` specifically `LinkedHashMap` if you want to maintain the insertion order or else `HashMap`